# ICS ROM For Galaxy S

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I want to update My Galaxy S with an ICS Android Version But I Can't find a stable One, I tried some ROMs on the net but they are broken with missing functionality and they slow down my phone. So I have turned back to Gingerbread. If someone has an already tried, tested ROM for Galaxy S could they please provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://aokp.co/index.php/releases/_/build-38-r24) is the most recent build for the [Android Open Kang Project](http://aokp.co/site/), which is ICS roms based and improved upon CM9. I have used these for my EVO and they are spectacular thus far. They're still beta, and while force closes are expected, they are few and far between. These builds have been great!

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have a Galaxy S to test on, and they don't have a discussion thread for it :/ but as long as you do a Nandroid, you can test all you want!